# Join multiple table and select top with multiple result LinQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

i have three tables:
Category, Product and Discount.

```
public class Category
   {
     public string CatName { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
   }
  public class Product
   {
     public string ProductName { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int CatId { get; set; }
     public int? OrderDisplay { get; set; }
   }
 public class Discount
   {
     public double Discount { get; set; } 
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
   }
```

My expect result like:

```
var result  = new List<Result>(){
   Category,
   List<Product> (Top5),
   Discount
}
```

Tried:

```
var query = from m in _catRepository.GetAll() 
                        select new
                        {
                            m.CatName,
                            m.Id, 
                        } into mn
                        join p in _proRepository.GetAll()
                            on mn.Id equals p.CatId 
                            into pr
                        let prj = pr.Take(5)
                        select new 
                        {
                            Pro = prj,
                            Cat = mn
                        };
```

but pr.Take(5) execute in memory, i dont want this.

can i execute in 1 query using linq to sql, so is it possible, or have any suggest for me?

Comment: Do you have a framework that your using?  Entity Framework, perhaps?

Comment: show us your models and framework

Comment: Yes, i used Entity framework core

Comment: What is the criteria for top 5?  Is it price, date, size?

Comment: var query = from m in categoryRepository.GetAll() where m.IsActive && m.ParentId.HasValue 
                join p in _productRepository.GetAll()
                    on m.Id equals p.CategoryId
                join pm in _discountRepository.GetAll()
                    on p.Id equals pm.ProductId
                    into grp
                select grp

with GetAll() is IQueryable

Comment: i just want to select top 5 from product sorted by OrderDisplay

Comment: @SonNguyen How do those tables relate to each other?  Can you show us your models? Also, if you use `@username` the user will be notified that you posted a message.

Comment: Where did `OrderDisplay` come from (it isn't in your question)? What is its type? Show us the models for your tables... show us the code you have tried.

Comment: @NetMage i updated my post, can you help me?

Comment: Where did you sort by `OrderDisplay`? You show `Id` in your code but not `Discount`?